# antlr4 line 1:10 mismatched input when using conflicting names

Tags: antlr4

I am using a limit token in my sql grammar. It works fine, but when I use the column name same as the token name I get into problem. I have a column name that is also the same name as of `limit`. How do I solve this issue?

Output:

```
line 1:10 mismatched input 'limit' expecting VAL
line 1:10 mismatched input 'limit' expecting VAL
```

Input:

```
select a, limit from abc limit 55 ;
```

Grammar:

```
grammar SQLCmd;

parse : sql
;

sql : ('select' ((columns (',' columns)*)|count) 'from')
      tables
      ('where' condition ((and|or) condition)*)*  (limit)? ';'
;

num : NUM
;

count : 'count(*)'
;

columns : VAL
;

limit : 'limit' num
;

tables : VAL
;

condition : ( left '=' right )+
;

and : 'and'
;

or : 'or'
;

left : VAL
;

right : VAL
;

NUM : [0-9]+
;

VAL : [*a-z0-9A-Z~?]+
;


WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expand your `columns` rule to allow `limit`:

```
columns
  : VAL
  | 'limit'
  ;
```

Comment: @user3536913 a token can only have one type, and the lexer runs before the parser. Since the same input text `limit` matches both `'limit'` and `VAL`, it will be assigned a type based on the rule which appears first. Implicitly-defined rules (as a result of using literals in parser rules) are always the first rules in the lexer.